# Consuming overloaded methods in a .Net Webservice from Java

Tags: java, axis, jax-rpc

I'm trying to access this webservice http://webservices.esalestax.net/CertiTAX.NET/certicalc.asmx?wsdl. It's a .Net implementation with overloaded methods. I have no problems accessing it from .Net. However, there are two problems when accessing it from Java. Since, it is a RPC Styled service, I'm using Axis to consume the service. However, as you can see from the wsdl, it has overloaded operations ie there is more than one operation with the same name under the same port. Axis throws the DuplicateOperation Exception when trying to generate the proxies. I understand that the webservice specifications don't allow overloading. Is there a way to generate the proxies in Java without tampering with the wsdl? I'm using Axis version 1.4.